# Подправить запрос(ы) в БД - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

ER диаграмма,та что плохая [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Новая ER - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прощу вашей помощи, как подредактировать запрос(-ы) или если есть более лаконичное решение, то подскажите.
Буду рад любой помощи.Спасибо!

Первый запрос: **Как вывести данные о спортсмене?**

> 1.Вывести таблицу распределения мест в соревновании 'открытый чемпионат' в городе 'Киев' по 'шахматам' в 2017 г.

```
SELECT Position 
FROM Result 
WHERE ID_Competition =(SELECT ID_Competition 
                       FROM Competition 
                       WHERE Name="Открытый чемпионат" AND City = "Киев" AND 
                       YEAR(Date)=2017 AND ID_Kind = 2)
```

Второй запрос: **Добавить вложенный запрос, чтобы определить количество спорт больше трёх.**

```
2.Определить спортсменов, которые выступают более чем в 3 видах спорта.

SELECT ID_Athlete, ID_Competition 
FROM Result
WHERE ID_Athlete IN (SELECT ID_Athlete 
                     FROM Result GROUP BY ID_Athlete HAVING COUNT(*)>2)
```

Третий запрос:**Преподаватель говорит, что "Неверная связь между результатом и видом спорта", не приходит в голову ничего.**

> 3.Вывести список спортсменов, превысивших мировые рекорды.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Result.Total_Result AS T_Result, Kind_of_sport.Record AS T_Kind_of_sport 
FROM Result 
           INNER JOIN Kind_of_sport ON Result.ID_Competition = 
           Kind_of_sport.ID_Kind 
           WHERE Result.Total_Result > Kind_of_sport.Record
```

Четвёртый запрос:**Проверить что  ID_Competition - это бег, по сути мы уже заведомо знаем, что это бег, так каким образом это проверить? Сделать связи двух таблиц?( A.ID_Competition = B. ID_Competition)**

> 4.Определить наилучший показатель заданного спортсмена в виде спорта 'бег'.

```
SELECT ID_Athlete, MIN(Total_Result) 
       FROM Result 
       WHERE ID_Competition = 1 AND ID_Athlete = 7
```

Исходник:(не получилось загрузить БД, если понадобится, загружу через ФО)

INSERT INTO `Result` (`ID_Result`, `ID_Athlete`, `ID_Competition`, `Position`, `Total_Result`) 
INSERT INTO `Athlete` (`Full_Name`, `Year_of_birth`, `Command`, `Sports_category`, `ID_Athlete`) 
INSERT INTO `Competition` (`ID_Competition`, `Name`, `Date`, `ID_Kind`, `Country`, `City`)
INSERT INTO `Kind_of_sport` (`ID_Kind`, `Name_Kind`, `Unit`, `Record`, `Date`)

Comment: Можете выкинуть Вашу диаграмму в ту мусорку, из которой взяли её, она лишь сбивает с толку: минут пять, глядя на неё, пытался понять - как же связан вид спорта... хоть с чем-нибудь? Структуру таблиц нормальную дайте, а то это невозможно разобрать.

Comment: Я полностью вас понимаю, но сам преподаватель нарисовал её такой.
Поэтому и пошёл сюда за наводками.
Если я не понял вопроса, прошу подправить меня.
Необходимо более структурно описать ер?

Comment: Извиняюсь, был не прав. Выкиньте преподавателя :D Ну или хотя бы (после того как зачет получите) скажите ему что-то типа "кстати, Ваша схема - гмно". Ну а по делу, если Вы собираетесь работать в будущем с базами данных, да еще и конкретно с mysql - сразу забудьте даже про саму возможность выполнения подзапроса. Или в условии задачи именно строго поставлено, что можно использовать подзапросы и нельзя использовать JOIN-ы? Что вообще можно использовать?

Comment: В рисунке есть одно белое пятно. Есть таблица Вид_Спорта с первичным ключом ИД_Вида_Спорта, но ни одна таблица не содержит внешнего ключа ИД_Вид_Спорта. Возможно, что либо преподаватель её забыл нарисовать, либо вы неправильно нам начертили. Логичнее всего, что это поле окажется на таблице Соревнования (вероятно связь один-ко-многим: один вид спорта - много соревнований), но лучше не гадать, а уточнить задачу прежде чем бросаться писать конкретные запросы.

Comment: Про JOIN - даже не задумался, спасибо за наводку. Можно использовать всё, но так, чтобы "Это было обоснованно и запрос не был излишним"

Вы правы, кто-то не дописал внешний ключ в ER, моя ошибка.(.p/s по инсерту видно, что ID_Kind- внешний ключ соревнованиях)
сейчас подправлю.

Comment: Спасибо, вот теперь можно читать запросы. Присоединяюсь к замечанию по JOIN. Первый же запрос можно переписать на JOIN и это будет намного более чистый и понятный код. Потренируйтесь, навык чтения/написания JOIN вам поможет с более сложными запросами.

Comment: По третьему вопросу: результаты к виду спорта явно клеятся через таблицу "соревнования". правда в соревнованиях поле вид спорта забыли нарисовать. его там надо дорисовать и через него и идти

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/4udwivc_Qbi_X7kxrRXeUw.png

Comment: @W0p, закончил. если что непонятно - спрашивайте.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский, всё круто, главное понятно.
Вот такой вопрос, в 3м запросе вы используете SELECT DISTINCT,  для получения уникальных строк?(не использовал его).

Но теперь самый главный вопорос, INNER JOIN `Competition` `c` USING (`ID_Result`) - ID_Result - необходимо добавить в Competition верно?(это внешний ключ)?

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Такой вопрос, GROUP BY использовать по ключевому полю разрешается? Меня учили, что это грубая ошибка, гугл ответов на дал.

Comment: @W0p, SELECT DISTINCT - да, для получения уникальных строк. Можно вместо него и GROUP BY использовать. Но, учитывая, что в данной ситуации строки небольшие - то, как мне кажется, лучше всё-таки DISTINCT. По поводу того что "грубая ошибка" - очень интересное мнение, и я возможно даже прислушаюсь к нему, как только аргумент хоть один приведут)

Comment: @АлександрБелинский https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756395/ 

Если не затруднит - зайдите в новую тему)
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вопрос, просто аккуратно идём от **вида спорта** и до **атлета**:

```
SELECT `a`.*, `r`.`Position`, `Total_Result`
FROM `Kind_of_sport` `k`
INNER JOIN `Competition` `c` USING (`ID_Kind`)
INNER JOIN `Result` `r` USING (`ID_Competition`)
INNER JOIN `Athlete` `a` USING (`ID_Athlete`)
WHERE
    `k`.`Name_Kind` = 'шахматы' AND
    year(`k`.`DATE`) = 2017 AND
    `c`.`City` = 'Киев' AND
    `c`.`NAME` = 'открытый чемпионат';
```

Второй вопрос, последнюю таблицу не клеим, потому что по условию нас не интересуют данные из неё, а идентификатор вида спорта мы можем взять и из таблицы "соревнования":

```
SELECT `a`.*, count(DISTINCT `c`.`ID_Kind`) as `count`
FROM `Athlete` `a`
INNER JOIN `Result` `r` USING (`ID_Athlete`)
INNER JOIN `Competition` `c` USING (`ID_Competition`)
GROUP BY `c`.`ID_Kind`
HAVING `count` > 3;
```

Третий вопрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `a`.*
FROM `Athlete` `a`
INNER JOIN `Result` `r` USING (`ID_Athlete`)
INNER JOIN `Competition` `c` USING (`ID_Competition`)
INNER JOIN `Kind_of_sport` `k` USING (`ID_Kind`)
WHERE `r`.`Total_Result` > `k`.`Record`;
```

Четвертый вопрос:

```
SELECT `a`.*, MAX(`Total_Result`) as `best_in_beg_result`
FROM `Athlete` `a`
INNER JOIN `Result` `r` USING (`ID_Athlete`)
INNER JOIN `Competition` `c` USING (`ID_Competition`)
INNER JOIN `Kind_of_sport` `k` USING (`ID_Kind`)
WHERE `k`.`Name_Kind` = 'бег'
GROUP BY `a`.`ID_Athlete`;
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь (я так думаю) понимание пришло.
Сейчас читаю про дожоины и юсинг.
Дабы закрепить материал, думаю сделать другой вариант.
Если появятся вопросы или мнение от эксперта, могу ли вас призвать?

Comment: USING - я сам не использовал ни разу, т.к. обычно в табличках нет всяких "ID_Athlete", а просто пишется "id". Возможно, кстати, и не работает оно так, так что, напишите, если что) Ну на крайняк можно его просто поменять на `ON r.ID_Athlete = a.ID_Athlete` - это вместо `USING (ID_Athlete)`, ну и дальше все вхождения аналогично.

Comment: @W0p, зачем меня призывать, я ж не демон какой-то... пишите просто вопрос новый - кто-нибудь да ответит. Если же уточнения касательно этого конкретного ответа - в комментариях пишите (насколько я понял, так это тут делается).

Comment: Второй запрос, мы имеем ID_Result, это не работает, мне надо добавить ID_Result внешним ключём?Или я не понял.

Comment: @W0p, не, просто у меня голова уже плохо соображает. Там должно быть "ID_Competition" - по сути, просто поле, по которому эти две таблицы связаны - competition и result. Ответ изменил.

Comment: @ Да тут легко запутаться с этими ID)
Теперь понятно всё. Спасибо большое!