# Подкорректировать запросы в MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Вывести предприятия, являющиеся нерентабельными в текущем году.

Я предположил, что можно использовать формулу "выручку - закупочная цена* на объём" и когда она не будет меньше 0 (то есть минус), то предприятие не ушло в минус( хотя надо ещё вычислить ЗП сотрудников и т.д, но такого в таблице нет)

```
SELECT `Profit`, `s`.*
FROM `Company` `k`
INNER JOIN `Supplies` `s` USING (`ID_Company`)
INNER JOIN `Production` `p` USING (`ID_Production`)
WHERE `k`.`Profit`-`s`.`Cost_Price`*`s`.`Size` > 0
```

**Теперь добавил выборку по году и ничего не выводит, в чём проблема, не понятно.**

```
SELECT `Profit`, `s`.* 
FROM `Company` `k`
 INNER JOIN `Supplies` `s` USING (`ID_Company`)
 INNER JOIN `Production` `p` USING (`ID_Production`)
 WHERE `k`.`Profit`-`s`.`Cost_Price`*`s`.`Size` < 0 and YEAR(`s`.`Date_Supplies` = 2017);
```

> Определить, предприятие какого вида собственности является ведущим в
>   поставке заданного вида продукции.

**Запрос мне не дался и я запутался.**

```
SELECT `Profit`, `k`.* 
    FROM `Company` `k`
     INNER JOIN `Supplies` `s` USING (`ID_Company`)
     INNER JOIN `Production` `p` USING (`ID_Production`)
     WHERE `k`.`Main_Voew_Products` = `p`.`Name_Production` and MAX(Size)
```

> Определить объем дохода на одного работника в каждом предприятии.

**Решил что при деление Выручки на работников - получим нужный объём, корректен ли запрос?**

```
  SELECT `Profit`, `k`.* ,`k`.`Profit`/`k`.`Workers_Country` 
    FROM `Company` `k`
```

> Вывести список продуктов, для которых закупочная цена ниже
>   себестоимости производителя.

**Верно ли составлен запрос? А если по структуре, то у меня нет производителя?(но это не важно)**

```
SELECT `s`.* 
FROM `Production` `p` 
INNER JOIN `Supplies` `s` USING (`ID_Production`) 
WHERE `s`.`Cost_Price` > `p`.`Purchase_Price`
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE `Company` (
    `ID_Company` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name_Company` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `Date_Registration` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Property_Style` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `Workers_Country` INT(5) NOT NULL,
    `Main_View_Products` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `Advanced_In_Technologies` bool NOT NULL,
    `Profit` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Note` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Company`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Production` (
    `ID_Production` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `Name_Production` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `Unit` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
    `Purchase_Price` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Production`)
);

CREATE TABLE `Supplies` (
    `ID_Supplies` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ID_Company` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `ID_Production` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Date_Supplies` DATE NOT NULL,
    `Size` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `Cost_Price` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID_Supplies`)
);

ALTER TABLE `Supplies` ADD CONSTRAINT `Supplies_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Company`) REFERENCES `Company`(`ID_Company`);

ALTER TABLE `Supplies` ADD CONSTRAINT `Supplies_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_Production`) REFERENCES `Production`(`ID_Production`);
```

---

Comment: первый запрос очевидно опечатка: `YEAR(`s`.`Date_Supplies` = 2017);` - равенство 2017 нужно вынести за функцию :D

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы препод Вас ненавидел - спросите его, а зачем вообще писать при определении поля `int(5)`, `int(11)` - что это дает? спойлер: [ничего](https://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/numeric-types.html) (чаще всего).

Comment: Второй запрос: `SELECT
    DISTINCT z.Name_Production, z.Property_Style
FROM
    (SELECT p.Name_Production, p.ID_Production, SUM(s.Size) as sumSize, k.ID_Company, k.Property_Style
FROM Production p
INNER JOIN Supplies s USING (ID_Production)
INNER JOIN Company k USING (ID_Company)
GROUP BY k.ID_Company, p.ID_Production
ORDER BY ID_Production, sumSize DESC) z;`. Но тут уже я не уверен - проверьте сами. По остальным вопросам - откуда такая неуверенность? Возьмите да проверьте на каких-нибудь данных - сами ручками посчитайте и посмотрите, совпадает ли с результатом запроса.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский так и сделаем. По поводу GROUP BY - 
он же группирует повторяющиеся значения, так вот, если столбец ключ (то у него нет повторений, так?) , тогда его не стоит использовать?

Comment: GROUP BY - а, ну почти верно. Это если делать запрос по одной таблице только, но ведь мы делаем JOIN - и у нас получается, что на одну запись из первой таблицы приходится несколько записей второй. А по поводу int(5) - и это, быть может, сработало бы, если бы не одно "но"... [Ссылку](https://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/numeric-types.html) я Вам выше дал, конкретно прочитайте от слов "Это необязательное указание количества" и до конца предложения.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский Понял, спасибо. Ещё есть куча вопросов, часть я задам сейчас, надеюсь вы ответите, а так же узнаю у преподавателя.
Ибо информации нет почти)
Как писать такое? (или лучше задать вопрос не в комментариях?)
 (запрос с использованием косвенно связанных таблиц и запрос с использованием рекурсивного соединения.)

Answer (score 1):

Второй запрос у вас неправильный, исправте так:

```
SELECT `Profit`, `s`.* 
FROM `Company` `k`
 INNER JOIN `Supplies` `s` USING (`ID_Company`)
 INNER JOIN `Production` `p` USING (`ID_Production`)
 WHERE `k`.`Profit`-`s`.`Cost_Price`*`s`.`Size` < 0 
   and YEAR(`s`.`Date_Supplies`) = 2017;
```